# Strange behaviour in PrimeFaces DataTable while Lazy-Loading (Video inside ;))

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Good evening from germany !

I have a very strange behaviour with the PrimeFaces DataTable component:

I have a simple pojo, a EJB which get out the POJOs from the DB, a Controller for my JSF Page and a CDI Bean which implements the LazyDataModel from Primefaces. Everything works as expected. The pagination between the Sites is working, the filter and also the sorting. But when i click a Button in the DataTable-Row with an ActionListener, everything stops working. The pagination doesn't work (althoug a Request/Response is done...very strange) until i reload the page.

I've made a little video for better understanding:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2PgQCNIVQc

I thought, that the EJB Call must be the Problem, but i was wrong. I've made a little (very quick and dirty ;)) example with a simple ArrayList and I'm able to reproduce this (Primefaces 4.0.x & Primefaces 5-Snapshot):

At first, my POJO:

```
public class User {
  private String login;
  private Date removeDate;

  public String getLogin() {
    return login;
  }

  public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
  }

  public Date getRemoveDate() {
    return removeDate;
  }

  public void setRemoveDate(Date removeDate) {
    this.removeDate = removeDate;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;

    User user = (User) o;

    if (!login.equals(user.login)) return false;

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return login.hashCode();
  }
}
```

The the very simple ControllerBean with the LazyLoad-Method and the Action:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LazyUserBean implements Serializable {

  private List<User> userEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      User newUser = new User();
      newUser.setLogin("User " + i);
      newUser.setRemoveDate(new Date());

      userEntityList.add(newUser);
    }
  }

  public List<User> getAllEntitiesLazy(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters, boolean invalidate) {
    List<User> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = first; i < this.userEntityList.size(); i++) {
      returnList.add(this.userEntityList.get(i));
    }
    return returnList;
  }

  public void removeDelDate(User user) {
    user.setRemoveDate(null);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
        Environment.getMessageResourceString("de.flatphormesmedia.wbsagentur.resources.lang_de", "persistence.recycleSuccess", new String[]{"bla"}), ""));
  }
}
```

The LazyLoadModel-Implementation:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class LazyUserModel extends LazyDataModel<User> implements Serializable {
  private List<User> datasource;

  @Inject
  LazyUserBean lazyUserBean;

  @Override
  public List<User> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
    this.datasource = this.lazyUserBean.getAllEntitiesLazy(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters, true);
    this.setRowCount(100);

    return datasource;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getRowKey(User user) {
    return user.getLogin();
  }
}
```

And at last the JSF Page:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://primefaces.org/ui ">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formEditUsers">
        <p:dataTable value="#{lazyUserModel}" var="user" lazy="true" paginator="true"
                     rows="13" id="tableUsers" emptyMessage="#{langRes['editUsers.emptyTable']}"
                     paginatorPosition="top">
            <!-- user login column -->
            <p:column headerText="#{langRes['editUsers.colHeadLogin']}" id="columnLogin"
                      filterBy="#{user.login}"
                      sortBy="#{user.login}">
                <p:outputLabel id="labelLogin" value="#{user.login}"/>
            </p:column>
            <!--delete date column-->
            <p:column headerText="#{langRes['setupAddresses.colHeadDeleteDate']}" id="columnDeletedDate"
                      width="20%">
                <p:outputLabel id="labelDeletedDate" value="#{user.removeDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss"/>
                </p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>

            <!-- edit column -->
            <p:column id="columnEdit" width="10%" style="text-align: center">
                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{lazyUserBean.removeDelDate(user)}"
                                 update=":formEditUsers:tableUsers"
                                 process="@this" id="buttonRecycle" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w"
                                 style="height: 70% !important">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

As i said, very quick and dirty...but nothing special in here. It's driving me nuts since last saturday. What I'm doing wrong in here? Or is this a PrimeFaces-Bug? Can't believe, I'm the first one who discovers this behaviour. 
Thanks in advance !

**Update 1: I added the ajax="false" attribute to the CommandButton and with a full request it work's like a charm. Is there anything wrong with the button?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a primefaces bug. Fixed with r11009 (https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/detail?r=11009).

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have never seen before that a LazyDataModel is also a managed bean. Your code looks good, so maybe you should try to separate the model and the bean into different classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... i tried that immediately...but it's the same result.

Answer (score 0):

please try process=":formEditUsers:tableUsers" instead of process="@this"

Comment: Thanks! I thought so too, several days ago...but this changes nothing. Strange is, that i've i setup a button and make a request, after the paging, the datatable jumps to the page i clicked befoe the table request.